# Persisting Data from the UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, repository

I am doing a little testing with EF4.  I have built a simple DB which contains one table:
Table: Person
Column: Id
Column: Name

- I have a windows form application that contains a form with a gridview.
- I have the Model.edmx all setup and works correctly (tested without encapsulating the context).
- I have now encapsulated the context into a generic repository (Repository).  I am learning how to use Repository then I will work on UnitoOfWork.

  - My repository implements CRUD.
- My Repository has a method that returns all entities (public List GetAll()).
- The List is assigned to my bindingsource in my windows form.  This works, great.

My Problem:
I am a bit confused on how to persist data from the UI back to my datastore.

- Do I have to setup some method on the form that checks for data that changes/ed?
- How would I send that back to the repository?  Do I have to attach it to the context?

I hope someone can give me some direction.  Thanks to all in advance!  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I am using a solution that I hope is correct...  I am using the bindingsource's listchanged event to notify the repo to CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

An event will need to fire on the form, be it a button click event or some other UI event.  In Windows forms, if you double click on a button in the designer, it will create the event handler for you.

In the event handler, you'll need to leverage another class, or use the EF Context directly.  Since you're going down the path of using a repository, you can leverage a repository class from your designer file, though I would recommed going through a Service layer to apply any business logic (i.e. UI calls Service Layer, Service Layer uses repository internally).

This keeps code separate and is much easier to maintain/reuse.

But, to persist data to datastore, it might look something like this...

```
public void SetPersonName(int personID, string personName)
{
     var context = new PersonContext(myConnectionString);
     var person = context.Persons.Where(x => x.PersonID == personID).FirstOrDefault();

     if(person == null)
     {
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Boo Hoo, person ID is invalid");
     }

     person.Name = personName;
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```